# Windows Server 2008R2 Remoteapp Authentication

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, authentication, rdp, windows-authentication, remoteapp

I have generated a Remoteapp MSI which I have installed on 2 machines and it prompts for authentication using the standard Windows auth prompt. on a third machine it opens up an rdp session and the user has to authenticate via an RDP session to the remote server login screen, which then, once completed reverts back to displaying the remoteapp as normal.
Might anyone be able to help me stop the second behaviour as with the first I can set the credentials to be remembered but not the second.
All 3 clients are windows 7

Comment: Compare the .rdp files that are used to launch the application to see if there are any differences between the machines where it works differently.  I have tried some modifications to one but I can't get the second behavior to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Given the rdp files came from the same MSI I doubt there would be a difference.

However in the end I found the configuration & policy setting which enabled Single Sign On which removed the need to log in again entirely.

References:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc742808.aspx

http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/q-how-can-i-enable-single-sign-my-remote-desktop-connections